# Why all of the sudden all commas in Power BI reports substituted with pipe symbol

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I just downloaded Power BI desktop. 
Opened my reports and for some reason all commas in measures are now pipes (|). 
If I try to use comma it gives me an error.

If I open the same report on another server then I see commas, no pipes.

What is going on?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to come from a local configuration. Can happen on Excel too. Usually you can modify the parameter "Region and Language Settings -> Additional settings..." and check the format on List Separator.

[image]
The problem can happen when you open a wrong formatted CSV file.